# iOS date format conversion?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to convert this format:

```
2013-10-29T07:32:02.000Z
```

Into:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ
```

Have tried:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];
NSDate *date  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];

// Convert to new Date Format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

But cannot get it to work, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your first format should resemble the source date.

Comment: How can i find out what format it is?

Comment: Maybe look at it?  You said it was "2013-10-29T07:32:02.000Z", so your date format should look like that.  See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial date format is incorrect. `2013-10-29T07:32:02.000Z` has a format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`.